# incorrect sql query created using setMaxResults with native query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, hibernate, jpa

I have this code where I am creating a native query and while executing the native query , I am using setMaxResults method.

```
List<?> resultList = (List<?>) getEntityManager(speedwingCustId, loggedInUserId).createNativeQuery(statement).setMaxResults(Integer.MAX_VALUE).getResultList();
```

this is my statement before the above code:

```
( SELECT IQV.VERSION_ID AS VERSION_ID FROM ITEM_QUERY_VIEW IQV WHERE  AVAILABLE_VALUE_ID IN (15611 ) AND EQUIPMENT_AVAILABILITY_ID = 1 AND REGION_ID IN (5 ,  8 ,  10 ,  14 ,  21 ,  20 ,  23 ,  24 ,  26 ,  35 ,  33 ,  39 ,  45 ,  55 ,  54 ,  53 ,  52 ,  63 ,  62 ,  61 ,  68 ,  71 ,  64 ,  65 ,  76 ,  72 )  AND VEHICLE_TYPE_ID IN (1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ,  5 ,  6 ,  7  )   GROUP BY VERSION_ID HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT(AVAILABLE_VALUE_ID)) = 1 )
```

this is my query while execution:

```
Hibernate:  ( SE TOP(?)LECT IQV.VERSION_ID AS VERSION_ID FROM ITEM_QUERY_VIEW IQV WHERE  AVAILABLE_VALUE_ID IN (15611 ) AND EQUIPMENT_AVAILABILITY_ID = 1 AND REGION_ID IN (5 ,  8 ,  10 ,  14 ,  21 ,  20 ,  23 ,  24 ,  26 ,  35 ,  33 ,  39 ,  45 ,  55 ,  54 ,  53 ,  52 ,  63 ,  62 ,  61 ,  68 ,  71 ,  64 ,  65 ,  76 ,  72 )  AND VEHICLE_TYPE_ID IN (1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ,  5 ,  6 ,  7  )   GROUP BY VERSION_ID HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT(AVAILABLE_VALUE_ID)) = 1 )
```

I am using MSSQL server and using JPA.

Comment: I *think* in native queries you will have to write also the limitting/pagination part by hand. I think the JPA spec does not require it explicitly, although I would expect it to work. Could you tell me what version of Hibernate do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you pass Integer.MAX_VALUE to setMaxResults()? It doesn't make sense. Try remove it or pass a meaningful number, for example, setMaxResults(30).

Comment: The amount of Data I am supposed to get is huge and I want to make sure that this is not more than Integer.MAX_VALUE